# Advantage of javascript: fun() vs fun()

Tags: javascript

What is the advantage of using

```
javascript: fun()
```

vs

```
fun()
```

in an inline event handler function?

Comment: Better to avoid inline event handlers altogether

Comment: @MauricePerry Swear I dont use it anywhere..But why is so is the question?

Comment: In short there is no advantage, it is a mistake made by a programmer who assumed that the `href` property has the same behavior as an `onchange` or other inline property.

Comment: @Pilot: kudos! you marked your own question as duplicate.

Comment: @abhitalks No gain in wasting your valuable time..

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:` is a protocol, to be used when a URL is required, e.g.:

```
<a href="javascript:fun();return false;">have fun</a>
```

If the JS is in an event handler attribute you shouldn't place the `javascript:` protocol before your code. E.g.:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fun();">have fun</a>
```

Comment: I dont think this answers the question, better close it as a duplicate